# Open Source VoIP/SIP Windows C API

Tags: c++, c, api, sip, voip

It seems there is something for apple, Open Source VoIP/SIP Objective-C Code

Is there a similar stack for WIndows that anyone HAS EXPERIENCE with and is easy to implement?

I have followed most of the leads here
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software .

But they are abandoned or not a Standard windows C API.

Answer (score 3):

I found this a while back and it looks really promising:

http://www.pjsip.org/